# change value to input repeated many time with the same class (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I have two "li" with the same class  "product cg-product-wrap" each of them contains an input "variation_id". I want when i click on< span class="link">  of the "li" change the content of their input and not all input using jQuery.

here is the HTML code

```
    <li class="product">
    <div class="cg-product-wrapper">
        <a href="#"><span class="link">objet1</span></a>
        <form class="cart variation_color_shop" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn_acheter">
                Acheter
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="product">
    <div class="cg-product-wrapper">
        <a href="#"><span class="link">objet2</span></a>
        <form class="cart variation_color_shop" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="2">
            <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn_acheter">
                Acheter
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

and here is the jQuery code

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.link', function(e) {

        $('.variation_color_shop').find('input[name="variation_id"], input.variation_id').val('newval').change();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `input[name="variation_id"], input.variation_id` and not just `.variation_id`? And ... where are you getting `'newval'` from?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the code please see the changes, no there is no particular for using "input[name="variation_id"], input.variation_id" and for 'newval' is just a example .thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to encounter the context and find the right input like

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.product', function(e) {
       $(this).find('.variation_color_shop input[name="variation_id"], .variation_color_shop input.variation_id').val('newval').change();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

where `$(this)` represents the clicked li

**EDIT**

Follwing code applies to you the changed structure in your question

```
 (function($) {
        $(document).on('click', 'span.link', function() {
           $(this).parents('li.product:first').find('.variation_color_shop input[name="variation_id"], .variation_color_shop input.variation_id').val('newval').change();
        });

    })(jQuery);
```

This time you are getting by `$(this)` the clicked span (with class 'link'). Via jQuerys [parents-function](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) you can navigate to ancestors (in your case the li) and then find inside of it what you are searching for.

Often it is usefull to combine the parents-function with the [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)-selector to reduce runtime and ensure you don't get ancestors which you were not aware of.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the code please see the changes and thank you